# Debugging several steps in one line using GDB

Tags: gcc, gdb

Trying to debug line that has line number `28` using `GDB`.

```
printf("file type: %s\n", filetype[(sb.st_mode >> 12) & 017]);
```

I do:

```
break 28
p sb.st_mode
```

Output:

```
$1 = 33270
```

If I press `n` code will go to next line. But I need result of `sb.st_mode >> 12`. And then the result of `(sb.st_mode >> 12) & 017`. How to achieve this?

What does `$1` means?

Comment: Is `ni` (next instruction) command, by any change, what you're looking for?

Comment: You can just print the result by `print (sb.st_mode >> 12)`, since you don't alter the result.

Comment: I would like to know how deep I can go with GDB debugging. Is it possible to kow which instruction is performed by ni ?

Answer (score 1):

You can enter more complex expressions at the `gdb` prompt, and the expression will be evaluated, if the language is `C` then this should be no problem.  So:

```
(gdb) p (sb.st_mode >> 12) & 017
(gdb) p filetype[(sb.st_mode >> 12) & 017]
```

In languages like `C++` where you have operator overloading then some of the above might not work, as the code for the operator function might not be available.  `gdb` will let you know when you hit such cases, so initially, don't worry about them.

When `gdb` prints a result it also assigns the result to a convenience variable for you, so you can easily access the result again, so:

```
(gdb) p $1
```

Will reprint the result that was assigned to `$1`.  In your case this might not seem very useful as you can easily re-evaluate your expression, but in some cases the result can't be re-evaluated.  For example, the `finish` command causes `gdb` to finish the current function.  The result returned by that function is printed, and assigned to a convenience variable.  Obviously you can't (easily) re-finish a function a second time, but if you want to re-print the result you can thanks to the convenience variable.

There's also a special convenience variable `$` which is always the last result that `gdb` printed.

You can also make use of convenience variables inside expressions, like this:

```
(gdb) p sb.st_mode
$1 = 33270
(gdb) p/x $1
$2 = 0x81f6
(gdb) p $1 >> 12
$3 = 8
(gdb) p $3 & 0x17
$4 = 0
```